# How could I make a react website to be completely bilingual

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my website to work with multiple languages. I have used react and node for implementing my website and it is completed for English language. And the requirement is that user can select the website language to be according to their preferences and it should be converted in that language.

I have come across with a package named as **react-i18-next** that is used for language conversion. But after going through the documentation, I have understood that only static texts can be converted with this package.

But the requirement is that, each and every texts which is visible on the webpage should be converted not just the static ones.

Comment: Bilingual is relatively easy ... so, when you say **multiple languages** you mean English and ONE other, right - of course, the answer really depends on the content, no idea what content you're providing, so, not much can be suggested, maybe some translation API that can do the hard work for you

Comment: You *can* translate every piece of text using `react-18n-next`. It has support for template strings which can insert dynamic values into a placeholder string. You define translation files for every component.

Comment: That package (and `i18next`, one of its dependencies which you have to implement to USE `react-i18next`) are meant to handle the process of determining, loading, and providing translated strings from storage. It's up to you to determine the structure of your locales, which languages are supported, and the actual static text that will be stored in each namespace. Meaning you have to either translate the values into other languages yourself, or find a service that'll do it for you and give you back filled in files.